# What is the 'captures' directory in android project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently, in one of my Android Project root, I can see a directory named **'captures'**. It contains several *.txt files name similarly - 
**SystemInfo_date_time.txt**

[image]

The file contains different kinds of information. 
I'm curious how they are generated, and if there's any way to utilize the information.

Android Studio - 2.2.3 | Gradle - 2.14.1

Comment: This is not common. Are you sure they are not created by any external library you are using?

Comment: @margabro I'm not sure. But the libraries are same as before it appeared.

Comment: This directory is by default included in `.gitignore`. So I assume, those are output files of some kind of plugin/library/etc.

Comment: @Slav yes, they seem to be included in .gitignore in recent AS versions.

Answer (score 7):

Those files are capture files generated when running the Layout Inspector or the Method Tracing in Android Studio (see [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector) for more information about Layout Inspector and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html#trace) for Method Tracing)

Comment: should we add it in gitignore?

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan For anyone using this feature yes, it makes sense to add it to your `.gitignore` as you probably don't need/want to share those files (it's a snapshot of your layout when you analyzed it)